# Saltstack cmd.run - if statement and unless

Tags: salt-stack

I manage the installation of our workstations with **Saltstack**. 
In my recipe for the ipa-client-automount installation on clients, I need to:

- set the location based on fqdn
- check if ipa-client-automount is already configured

Currently, I have the following state:

```
 ipa-client-automount:
  cmd.run:
    {% if salt['cmd.run']('hostname -f | grep domain1') %}
    - name: ipa-client-automount --location=linkedtodomain1 -U
    {% elif salt['cmd.run']('hostname -f | grep domain2') %}
    - name: ipa-client-automount --location=linkedtodomain2 -U
    {% endif %}
    - unless: python -c "from ipapython import sysrestore; from ipaplatform.paths import paths; statestore = sysrestore.StateFile(paths.IPA_CLIENT_SYSRESTORE); exit(not statestore.has_state('autofs'))"
```

The issue is that when adding the if and elif statement, it doesn't consider the unless. It runs directly the command without checking the unless condition.
Also, I'm sure that my unless statement is working, it was all fine with only one location.

How can I write this to have the if and unless working at the same time? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something like `- unless: false` ?

Comment: You also might want to try [`onlyif`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#onlyif)

Comment: I've tried the `- unless: false` , it runs the command anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working solution:

```
ipa-client-automount:
  cmd.run:
    - names: 
      {% if salt['cmd.run']('hostname -f | grep domain1') %}
      - ipa-client-automount --location=linkedtodomain1 -U
      {% elif salt['cmd.run']('hostname -f | grep domain2') %}
      - ipa-client-automount --location=linkedtodomain2 -U
      {% endif %}
    - unless: condition
```

It's not the cleanest solution but it worked for me. Don't know why this doesn't work on `names` but does on `name`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the if condition. If you use the `if salt['cmd.run']()` that way the first `if` will always be true.

In salt, a better approach would be to use the `host` grain with something like:

```
{% if grains.get('host') == 'domain1' %}
```

or, if you really want to use the `cmd.run` approach, try something like:

```
{% if salt['cmd.run']('hostname -f') == 'domain1' %}
```

Comment: The IF condition I'm using in my answer/workaround solution is working so that's not the main issue. But grains use is interesting, thanks.